# How can i htf.escape_sc string convert to html in plsql?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have string

```
encodeString = select htf.escape_sc('Please<B> escape <this> tag<html></html>');
```

i want to convert 'encodeString' variable to pure html code(Please escape  tag)

Is that possible do in pl/sql if yes how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
str1 := 'Please<B> escape <this> tag<html></html>';
str2 := regexp_replace(str1, '<.*?>');
```

or

```
select regexp_replace(col, '<.*?>') from table
```